# how to insert circle shapes into a word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-pia

I don't know how to insert a circle shape into my document. I'm using iterop.word intro c# and I need to insert 4 small circles into a clear document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a shapes to a word document, you can use the following method [Document.Shapes.AddShape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addshape%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and you can specify which shape you want to insert using [this enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msoautoshapetype.aspx).

So if you want to add a circle you can do

```
wordDocument.Shapes.AddShape((int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval,
        20, 20, 40, 40);
```